# fixed sidebar fluid content, "clear both" issue

Tags: css, fixed, sidebar, fluid-layout

Check code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rahim701/jnU3W/

Here we have a left sidebar (fixed width) and right content box (fluid width)
Problem is, I want to use css clear at content box.
But If I use "clear both", it's also catch left sidebar to clearing.
Please check code to be sure.
There I write "Bangladesh" after clearing.
But it was there after a big white space, after finishing left sidebar.

Any solution?

I saw some other post with almost same title, but didn't find any answer.

Comment: Why do you need to use a `clear` there? Can you float the `content` div?

Comment: It's not the cleanest solution ever (that's why I'm not posting it as an answer, I'm hoping someone comes up with a better solution), but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/jnU3W/1/ You need to float `#content` to the right, but you cannot use `width: auto` anymore. So, I used a padding + negative margin on `#sidebar` to achieve the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you right but as I understand a simple clear:right will do it

Comment: This does seem to work. Anything which you needed to clear would need to be floated right, however.